# Ian McEwan's quote "No more magical realism" in Saturday

Tags: quote-source, ian-mcewan, saturday

I read Ian McEwan's Saturday and remember a part where the daughter, who was into poetry, tried to get her father, a neurosurgeon, to read more books. She recommended South American writers like Gabriel Garcia Marquez. The father answered something like:

> No more magical realism, please. Reality ought to offer plenty of material for a novel.

I cannot find this quote so maybe I got the words wrong or it's from a different book. Does it ring a bell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Anna Karenina* and *Madame Bovary* […] had the virtue, at least, of representing a recognisable physical reality, which could not be said for the so-called magical realists she [Daisy] opted to study in her final year. What were these authors of reputation doing—grown men and women of the twentieth century—granting supernatural powers to their characters? He [Henry] never made it all the way through a single one of these irksome confections. And written for adults, not children. In more than one, heroes and heroines were born with<sup>1</sup> or sprouted wings<sup>2</sup>—a symbol, in Daisy’s term, of their liminality; naturally, learning to fly became a metaphor for bold aspiration. Others were granted a magical sense of smell,<sup>3</sup> or tumbled out of high-flying aircraft.<sup>4</sup> One visionary saw through a pub window his parents as they had been some weeks after his conception, discussing the possibility of aborting him.<sup>5</sup> […]
>
> “No more magic midget drummers,”<sup>6</sup> he pleaded with her by post, after setting out his tirade. “Please, no more ghosts, angels, satans or metamorphoses. When anything can happen, nothing much matters. It’s all kitsch to me.”
>
> <sub>Ian McEwan (2005). *Saturday*, chapter 2. London: Jonathan Cape.</sub>

My best guess as to the works referred to:

1. Gabriel García Márquez (1965), ‘A Very Old Man with Enormous Wings’.
2. Angela Carter (1984), *Nights at the Circus*.
3. Patrick Süskind (1985), *Perfume: The Story of a Murderer*.
4. Salman Rushdie (1988), *The Satanic Verses*.
5. Ian McEwan (1987), *The Child in Time*.
6. Günter Grass (1959), *The Tin Drum*.

Characters having or sprouting wings is a common trope and McEwan might have had different works in mind, for example *Mr Pye* (1953) by Mervyn Peake, or *Moonlight on the Avenue of Faith* (2000) by Gina B. Nahai.

The inclusion of one the author’s own novels in this list is a signpost as to how seriously the reader is intended to take Henry’s tirade.